# Do lightsabers smell?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

In real live plasmas give off some odor. The closest to a reference I find is [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/6h3wq8/why_does_plasma_smell_the_way_it_does/). But one can easily check for himself. It's mostly ozone what one smells (smell of thunderstorms).

So I was wondering as lightsabers are kind of plasma and we sometimes see even flashes between blades - do lightsabers have a peculiar odor?

I would especially be interested if there was anything mentioned in books - like one could smell there was recently a fight in a room.

Comment: Are you especially interested in the EU novels? There are literally dozens of references to lightsabers having a "tang" and "smell" of ozone.

Comment: I didn't realise there are. But as you ask - is there any instance where this was used on it's own? say to track someone, or as in the question as evidence there was a battle (which otherwise wouldn't be apparent).

Comment: No, they don't smell. They've got no nose.

Comment: Seems like they must smell the same as the beam of a super-hot laser (ozone).  Of course there could be less smell because a light saber inexplicably has properties and limitations that are different from a laser.

Comment: @MarkRogers or real live plasma.  though I was not sure chemistry in a galaxy-far-away would work the same.   Now I wonder whether Vaders asthma was induced by inhaling all this ozone...

Comment: I don't think you'd need the smell of ozone to know that Kylo Ren just had a hissy fit.

Comment: @NicholasShanks, You're saying that they _stink_ then?

Comment: Lightsabers smell like burnt nose hairs.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There seems to be a particular smell associated with lightsabers; **Ozone.**

> ***A burning blade of green slanted across the sergeants face so close he
> could smell the ozone,** and the hunchback wasn’t a hunchback anymore:
> he now held a lightsaber the color of a summmer sky, and he said in a
> clipped, educated Coruscanti accent, “Please don’t try to resist. No
> one has to get hurt.”*
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Revenge of the Sith - Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(novel))</sup></sub>

It's more pronounced when the saber comes into contact with electricity

> *He was lost in his own thoughts when Qui-Gon swung about with such
> swiftness it caught the boy completely by surprise. Down swept the
> Jedi’s lightsaber in a brilliant arc, cutting through the shadows
> between two buildings, clashing momentarily with something made of
> metal that shattered in the wake of the weapon’s passing.
> *
> *Qui-Gon clicked off the lightsaber and knelt to inspect a cluster of
> metal parts still sparking and fizzing in the sand. **The acrid smell of
> ozone and burning insulation hung in the dry air.***
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: The Phantom Menace - Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_I:_The_Phantom_Menace_(novel))</sup></sub>

and

> *“Help me! I can’t hold on any longer!” The yellow glare from
> Palpatine’s eyes spread outward through his flesh. His skin flowed
> like oil, as though the muscle beneath was burning away, as though
> even the bones of his skull were softening, were bending and bulging,
> deforming from the heat and pressure of his electric hatred. “He is
> killing me, Anakin-! Please, Anaaahhh-“*
>
> *Mace’s blade bent **so close to his face that he was choking on ozone.**
> “Anakin, he’s too strong for me-“*
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Revenge of the Sith - Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(novel))</sup></sub>

Comment: wow - how do you answer so quickly? :D

Comment: @bdecaf - Because I've read these. And [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/) and the [Quality Check](https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=125428) app allow me to search very very quickly for specific quotes

Comment: I'm convinced that Valorum is some kind of robot at this point.

Comment: @Recelica - Input Error. Does not compute.

Comment: Seriously though, how long have you been #1 for? You're on every post I see, it's truly astounding how much you get around lol.

Comment: @Recelica - I overtook DVK last year

Comment: To get back to the question.  The first quote reads as if the odor is very faint (only noticeable when extremely close). But the other two read as if it was very strong (noticeable from distance, strongly inconvenient when close). Which would describe it better?

Comment: @bdecaf - I think the implication is that you get more ozone, the more the blade is interacting with the air. Merely waving it around generates a little ozone. Cutting something with it generates a lot.

Comment: @Recelica  If you think Valorum is a robot then I'd hate to think what you would consider Jon Skeet to be on https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet

Comment: @PeterM - at least for Jon, it's part of his actual job to post.

Comment: Cutting something with plasma will release all sorts of toxic chemicals. Stand there and cut through enough brass and you're going to get [the chills](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_fume_fever). The more it's in contact with a substance other than air, the less ozone it will produce.